# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/AppBar'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**EDIT: Just discovered that not one single module installed through `npm install --save` can be resolved. The issue seems to be therefore with all modules even though they are located inside node_modules folder.**

I have been debugging this error for the last 2 hours. Note that the application has been created with `create-react-app` tool.

This is how I am importing the module:

```
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
```

This is the `package.json` snippet:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.1",
...
```

Comment: Did you try to delete your node_modules and try again?

Comment: share you webpack config if it is importing node_modules

Comment: @Anas yes I tried that already

Comment: @SakhiMansoor this app was create with `create-react-app` and just found out that all modules cannot be imported

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try - `yarn add @material-ui/core`

This resolved the broken dependencies between materialui and react.
Worked for me in my case, it was @material-ui/core/chippedInput that was missing.

Comment: Please post your error here. Don't mix npm and yarn package management.

Answer (score 15):

The solution that worked for me is the following:

```
npm install  @material-ui/core
```

Check the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use *material-ui* inside a docker container via *docker-compose*, when I got the same error. I had to reinitialize *docker-compose* via `docker-compose down` before running `docker-compose up --build`. Afterwards the import worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while trying to work with the material-ui table. Additional to installing the `@material-ui/core` via npm, make sure you install `npm install @material-ui/icons`, from https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#svg-icons

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed was, just by npm install it is not installing @material-ui/core package,
we need to install it separately by npm install @material-ui/core. This method is the same for @material-ui/icons

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was following a tutorial and ended up with an import as

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
```

Instead of using the following which is in documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/).

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
// or
import { AppBar } from '@material-ui/core';
```